# Output of command not in stderr nor stdout

Tags: shell, stdout, stderr

I've stumbled on this issue, so I'm wondering how is this possible?

Standard run of command:

```
# zabbix_sender -c zabbix_agentd.conf -k mmysql.QCInserts -o 14
info from server: "Processed 0 Failed 1 Total 1 Seconds spent 0.000017"
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
```

OK, lets try to get the first line only:

```
# zabbix_sender -c zabbix_agentd.conf -k mmysql.QCInserts -o 14 | head -1
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
```

What about standard head?

```
# zabbix_sender -c zabbix_agentd.conf -k mmysql.QCInserts -o 14 | head 
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
```

Inverse grep? sed? tee?!?!?!!?

```
# zabbix_sender -c zabbix_agentd.conf -k mmysql.QCInserts -o 14 | grep -v pero
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1

# zabbix_sender -c zabbix_agentd.conf -k mmysql.QCInserts -o 14 | sed 's/foo/bar/'
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1

# zabbix_sender -c zabbix_agentd.conf -k mmysql.QCInserts -o 14 | tee
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
```

stderr to stdout?

```
# zabbix_sender -c zabbix_agentd.conf -k mmysql.QCInserts -o 14 2>&1 | tee
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
```

I'm really puzzled...

Comment: What were you expecting with `tee`? What happens if you run `zabix_sender <options> 2>&1 | head -1`?

Comment: I wonder if it is sending to stdin. If not then where did it get a file-descriptor of the tty.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can happen if the application is writing directly to the TTY instead of STDOUT or STDERR.

You can play with this behavior by comparing the 2 examples below

```
( echo foo ) &>/dev/null
( echo foo > $(tty) ) &>/dev/null
```

Notice the first doesn't show anything, but the second does. That's because we sent the output directly to the tty and bypassed the redirection to `/dev/null`.

You can get around stuff like this by using `script`

```
script -c '( echo foo > $(tty) ) &>/dev/null'  >/dev/null
```

Basically the `script` utility creates a fake tty and launches the command in that tty. Any output from the command is sent to STDOUT which you can then redirect as normal.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to "script"!  That's exactly the thing I needed to work around gpg/gpg2's stubborn insistence on not reading from stdin.

Comment: `script: illegal option -- c` :( Are there any other workarounds you know of?