# How to capture output that's not to stdout or stderr (direct to tty) in QNX?

Tags: tty

I have a utility `foo` that I want to grep output from, redirect, and otherwise do all the normal text manipulation stuff. But alas! Look at what it does...

```
$ foo
bar
$ foo > /dev/null
bar
$ foo 2> /dev/null
bar
$ foo | grep abc
bar
$ foo 2| grep abc
bar
```

Apparently the output is neither `stdout` nor `stderr`. Perhaps `foo` rights directly to the tty instead of to stdout. There is an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70901/174155) that provides a workaround using `script -c`. But alas again!

```
$ script -c foo > /dev/null
script: illegal option -- c
usage: script [-a] [file]
```

Perhaps my `script` utility is not the full version. The operating system is QNX.

For those of us who cannot use the `script -c` workaround, how can we easily capture the output? Is there a way to redirect the tty file itself, if that makes any sense?

Is it possible to do something like `foo (/dev/ttyp0)| grep abc`? That likely will not work exactly as shown, but is there a way to do something similar? An answer which requires the file to be redirected first (if that is even possible) is fine, so something like `/dev/ttyp0 please go to /dev/null ; foo` is ok.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to pipe the output of `foo` to `grep` and/or redirect `foo` output to a file.

Comment: Try `SHELL=/your/program script ...`.

Comment: also, if `script` insists to run `/bin/sh` or your login shell, it could tricked via the `ENV` variable to source a file with calls `exec /your/program`. What is the shell on qnx?

Comment: If `/your/program` doesn't accept or interprets the `-i` option specially, you could write a wrapper for it.

Comment: @mosvy That's an interesting idea. One would possibly have to strip the header and footer off from the output of `script` if that works.  Unfortunately I don't have a QNX system to test on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `foo` application is likely writing directly to the TTY.

Here's a script that does the same thing:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'bar' >$(tty)
```

Since your `script` utility can't be used to execute `foo` directly (only through the interactive shell that the utility starts), you will have to find another way of allocating a new TTY for the execution of the command.

One such way is using `ssh`:

```
ssh -t localhost "$PWD/foo" >output.log
```

This would (ab)use `ssh` to connect to `localhost`, forcing the allocation of a TTY with `-t`, and running the `foo` application located in the current directory.  The output of `foo`, including everything that was written te the TTY, to standard output and to standard error, would come back to you from the standard output of `ssh`, and you may then redirect it to wherever you want.

Comment: This does indeed work, thank you! My capture still is not working, but for unrelated reasons. Your suggestion is straightforward, simple, and did just as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

OK I use [script](https://manpage.me/?q=script) (on a BSD box) to *capture* the output of long runs of jobs, or build output. *This* is, I believe what you're running into. For example, from the man page:

```
-a      Append the output to file or typescript, retaining the prior contents.
```

look familiar? :)

The option `-F pipe` may provide you with a possible solution. But in the end, I'm not really sure, judging by your question, that [script](https://manpage.me/?q=script) is actually what you were looking for.

Have a look at the man page I linked to.

HTH

Comment: The user is on QNX. This is the manual for `script` on QNX: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/s/script.html  They want to execute the `foo` thing directly and pipe or redirect the output somewhere. You can't use QNX `script` to do that as it needs to run an _interactive_ shell session.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry. I saw the output from the OPs "solution", and looked exactly like the output from the man page I linked to. Thanks for the clarification, Kusalananda!

Answer (score 0):

If your program ignores the `-i` option, you can run it directly with

```
SHELL=/path/to/your/program script /dev/null > output
```

If it chokes on the `-i` option, you can create a wrapper for it.

```
$ cat wrapper
#! /bin/sh
exec /path/to/your/program
$ chmod 755 wrapper
$ SHELL=./wrapper script /dev/null > output
```